# tmux - attach to a session and specify window

Tags: bash, session, centos, sh, tmux

I have a script (.sh) and I want it to run in a existing tmux session. I have 1 session with 8 windows in.

Is there a command like `tmux a -t session-name`, which also specify the window?

And would a script like this work?

`#!/bin/bash
tmux a -t session-name #What ever to write to specify window# java -jar -Xmx4G -Xms4G Spigot.jar`

Answer (score 11):

You can change the active window of a session *before* you attach to the session.

```
tmux -t <session-name> select-window -t <windowID>
tmux a -t <session-name>
```

You can combine two `tmux` commands as well.

```
tmux -t session-name select-window -t <windowID> \; a
```

If you really want to run java, presumably you want to create a new window with `new-window`, rather than select an existing one with `select-window`.

---

Newer versions of `tmux` (at least 1.9; did the above ever work, perhaps in 1.6?) no longer appear to have a `-t` option to specify the session to apply commands to. Instead, each individual command specifies the session.

```
tmux select-window -t <session-name>:<windowID> \; a -t <session-name>
```

Comment: I get `tmux: illegal option -- t` on `tmux 2.2`.

Comment: I don't have an older version of `tmux` anymore to check what changed. In 2.2, though, I think you just specify the session as part of the target window: `tmux select-window -t <session>:<windowID>`.

Comment: Works absolutely perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: The downside to switching before attaching is that you affect any other client of the same session. My goal is usually to attach a new client and then switch to _a different window_ of the same session.

Answer (score 10):

You can specify the window after the session separated by a colon.

```
tmux a -t session:window
```

You can even attach to a specific pane.

```
tmux a -t session:window.pane
```

Pane can be a number starting from 0. Window can be a number or name.
`man tmux` has more info about different syntaxes allowed for `target-session`, `target-window`, and `target-pane`.

> target-window (or src-window or dst-window) specifies a window in the form session:window...

This syntax works on any other command like `send-keys`. If it's not working you may be on an older version of tmux and need to upgrade or try an approach suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

For tmux version 2.1 this works

```
tmux a -t  <session-name> \; select-window -t <windowID> \;
```